# jQuery Sortable using Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

In my Rails app, I'm trying to build a sortable list (following the [RailsCast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised)). I've got a Screen, which `has_many` Contents that are nested:

screen.rb:

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
end
```

content.rb:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :screen
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :screens do
  resources :contents do
    collection { post :sort }
  end
end
```

On my view for the Screen, I want to display a list of Contents that are sortable.

/screens/show.html.erb:

```
<ul id="content" data-update-url="<%= sort_screen_contents_path(@screen) %>">
  <% @screen.contents.each do |content| %>
    <li><%= content.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and the associated CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#content').sortable(
        axis: 'y'
        update: ->
            $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
    );
```

When I drag the content, my server log shows that it is passing the screen_id as the parameter, not the content position:

```
Started POST "/screens/2/contents/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 12:39:21 -0600
Processing by ContentsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"screen_id"=>"2"}
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I figure that the issue is probably where I'm defining the `data-update-url` in the view, since I'm passing in `@screen`, but it seems to require that when you have a nested resources. How should I be calling the `Content#sort` action? Is the issue somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use array notation as your update url is currently just passing the screen_id

```
data-update-url="<%= [:sort, @screen, @screen.contents]
```

Comment: Thanks, I had given that a shot before, but @screen.contents seems to be an array. My rendered HTML shows: `data-update-url="/screens/2/%23%3CActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Content:0x007faf6a666180%3E/contents/sort"` and I get a similar routing error associated with that.

Comment: Yeah sorry, upon thinking on it, that wouldn't have worked, i think it lies in your html markup, as the js code is serializing the screen div and not the child divs